# Independent set of events that their union happen in prob.1 implies the events are happening i.o

Tags: probability-theory

I'm pretty clueless with a proof in probability and i'll be happy for some help.

Let ${A_n}$ be an infinite set of independent events with $P(A_n) < 1$ for every n.
I want to prove that if $P(\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty A_n) = 1$ it follows that $P(A_n\space i.o.)=1$.

Thanks,
Ohad

Comment: Which theorems dealing with events of the form $[A_n\  \text{infinitely often}]$ do you know? There should be about one--and this is the one to apply here.

Comment: It's a tail event, i.e it has either prob. 1 or prob. 0 from the Kolmogorov 0-1 law.
But still, i can't connect that to find the solution.
I tried to prove by assume the contradiction and that didnt worked for me.

Comment: Yes--and to choose between 0 and 1, one looks at...

Comment: I have no idea...

Comment: B-r-l C-nt-ll-.

Comment: I don't see considering the terms how Borel-Cantelli can help me here.

Comment: Did, did you solved that using Borel-Cantelli lemmas?

Comment: What else... :-)

Comment: So can you please guide me?
I really cant see how to use Borel-Cantelli lemmas without knowing the probabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us try to make ends meet and see what happens...

- First, the condition that the event $\bigcup\limits_nA_n$ has probability $1$ means that the event $\bigcap\limits_nA_n^c$ has probability $0$, hence, by independence, that the infinite product $\prod\limits_n(1-P(A_n))$ is zero.
- On the other hand, by Borel-Cantelli, the event $[A_n\ \text{infinitely often}]$ has probability $1$ if and only if the series $\sum\limits_nP(A_n)$ diverges.

So, what is left to do is to figure out why the product being zero implies that the series diverges... And for *that*, the condition that no $1-P(A_n)$ is zero surely is useful. Can you connect the dots now?